# Service Call in ROSJava?

Tags: rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi everybody!

I'm trying to call a Service in ROSJava. The Service itself is running on ROS/Cpp.
What i'm looking for, is the command "rosservice call /EnableFreeSpaceOrientation true" in Java.
http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosjava
The "Calling a Service" part seems to be the solution?

Have i missed something? Maybe i'm to stupid to see it or find it! :D

Hope for help! Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10264/service-call-in-rosjava?/) by [Mr_Miyagi](https://answers.ros.org/users/599/mr_miyagi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2011-06-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Are you using the new, pure-Java rosjava or the old JNI-based rosjava?

FYI: we've just moved the JNI docs here:

http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosjava_jni

As for the new rosjava, it's still in an alpha state and service calls are not easy-to-use right now.

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2011-06-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0